# Probability Question. Finding P(A ∩ B).

Tags: probability

A lumber company has just taken delivery on a shipment of 10,000 2 ✕ 4 boards. Suppose that 40% of these boards (4000) are actually too green to be used in first-quality construction. Two boards are selected at random, one after the other. Let A = {the first board is green} and B = {the second board is green}.
(a) Compute P(A), P(B), and P(A ∩ B) (a tree diagram might help). (Round your answer for P(A ∩ B) to five decimal places.)

I drew out the tree diagram and I know that P(A)=.40 and P(B)=.40. My question is how to I find P(A ∩ B) without assuming independence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are given:  $P(A) = 0.4$.

$P(A \cap B) = P(B|A)P(A)$ (probability of $A$ times probability of $B$ *given that A occurred*.  If $A$ occurred (and you don't replace the green board into the collection), then there are 3999 green boards out of 9999, so $P(B|A) = {3999 \over 9999}$.

Putting this together:  $P(A \cap B) = 0.4 {3999 \over 9999} = 0.159976$.